# Error using * Inner matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, telecommunication

I'm trying to calculate some functions in matlab and I'm getting this error:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in set1 (line 11)
x = (Ac + m)*cos(2*pi*fc*t);
```

but I don't use any kind of matrix in my code. What is the problem about?

Here is my code:

```
fs = 10000;
Ts = 1/fs;
t = (0:Ts:10);
m = cos(2*pi*t);
plot(t,m);
figure;

Ac = 2;
fc = 500;
x = (Ac + m)*cos(2*pi*fc*t);
plot(t,x);
figure;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try elementwise multiplication by adding a dot before *:

```
x = (Ac + m).*cos(2*pi*fc*t);
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem